# Visual studio 2017 code color issue after update

Tags: visual-studio, themes, visual-studio-2017

I used to work comfortably with the Dark theme of VS. Today, I updated my VS to `v.15.2(26430.4)`, but it suddenly run into a visual problem.

The colours of the code in Dark mode are terrible. I almost cannot see them clearly.

Any way to fix it? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Yes, Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found some workarounds

1. by unchecking the `Enable rich client visual experience`. And then restart VS.

[image]

2. Another method is to choose color theme to `Light` and switch back to `Dark` again.

Comment: Switch to Light has resolved the display for me. Thank.

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me (amongst others)

Restarting VS fixed it. (No options changes, just exit and start again.)

UPDATE: This is on the user [feedback site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/54341/color-theme.html) and should be fixed by updating to 15.2 (26430.06) (published 12 May).

Answer (score 3):

They fixed problem and pushed another update today. Here's the release notes:

Release Date: May 12, 2017 - Visual Studio 2017 version 15.2 (26430.06)
Issues Fixed in this Release
This is the customer-reported issue addressed in this version:

The v15.2 dark color theme fails to load after F# component in .NET workload is installed.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes

Answer (score 2):

I am a dev. on the Visual Studio team. There are currently two official workarounds:

1. Uninstall the F# language support via the VS installer.
2. Ctrl+Q and search for 'theme' and select 'Environment -> General' and then switch from one theme to another and press 'Ok', then, repeat and switch back.

NOTE: Workaround #2 is only temporary. Installing a new extension or update will revert the colors back to their current state.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem.

In the Tools >> Option >> Text Editor >> C# >> Advanced >> Editor Color Scheme >> select different visual studio version

Answer (score 1):

Restarting VS did not work for me.

I fixed it like this: In VS go to `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> General -> Color theme`. Switched to `Light`, clicked OK and then changed back to `Dark`. After this everything looked normal.