# Visual studio 2017, editor different color

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Today I opened VS2017 and suddenly, the color of text in the editor has changed.
I tried to find solution on internet but no success. I repaired VS2017 but still no success.
Do you have any idea what is causing this?
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual studio 2017 code color issue after update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43914872/visual-studio-2017-code-color-issue-after-update)

Comment: @Richard I did not find it while searching.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I just updated VS2017 and everything is ok.